# How to submit a form internally?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, web

I am curious about submitting a form data internally.

Here is an example.

I want to register an account for a website. The website will give a form to register which upon submitting will create an account for me.

But I don't want to go to that site. Instead I'll give a form in my style and collect the same information. Upon submit, I want to create the account automatically. Automatically in the sense, I'll submit the form internally.

The reason why I need this feature is, I don't want my users to create a separate account in another website also. I mean it should save user's time in creating account only. Rest of the things will be taken care by me.

Please let me know if anyone had tried this and had success.

I know it is very difficult for existing accounts and some internal errors. But I also need to track them.

Please let know if this is possible or not.

**An Example**
There is site called **othersite.com** which has a form for creating / registering users.
I will a similar form to the user on **mysite.com**. But upon submit the form information is sent to both mysite.com and othersite.com. Both sites create accounts parallelly with a single form submission.

Comment: I didn't fully understand, can you describe a scenario of how it happens today and how you want it to be? Please consider describing from the user perspective.

Comment: So you want users to register on your website, then you want to post the same information to another form on another website? So scripting a regitstration on the other site?

Comment: yes. Example - Create a facebook accoutn from my website. I'll show the same form to the user. But in my style and in my web page. I'll let the user know that another account is automatically using the same information. Along side my website account

Comment: Use that website API than form itself.

Comment: use some Httpclient library.

Comment: @Innovation Can u please let me know the best libraries. Are you sure is my requirement possible?

Comment: Its all depends upon programming language you are using

Comment: It's a basic and really easy task to do. For how...it's a matter of where (server or client) and with which programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are working with AJAX requests and [CORS](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) enabled sites, which I assume is not the case, client side technologies ( browser/javascript ) will not help you much to do that.

You have to ask yourself what are the options to integrate with the second site in order to automatically create the account. Following some common patterns used these days:

- REST API: You have an url where you can use HTTP to talk to and ask to create the account. Many social networks and other popular services usually expose it.  [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)
- Database: Although it is less recommended you could just insert a new record into the account table if you own and have access to the database used by the second site.
- Client Libraries: Some sites provide client libraries so that you can use them together with your project code base. Eg: [Twitter Libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries)